# How much have carbon-based industries invested in anti-climate-change lobbying in Australia?

Tags: australia, lobbying

There are reports that oil, coal and gas industries in America have invested more than half a billion dollars on lobbying against acting on climate change. In Australia there are more than 540 'registered lobbyists, + many more unregistered. So I'm wondering how many of these are in the oil, coal and gas business, and how much do they spend on their lobbying?

Comment: Some links to the "reports" or the "more than 540 registered lobbyists" would improve this question.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://thenewdaily.com.au/money/finance-news/2019/05/19/oil-lobby-climate-change-policy/) tackles some very similar to what your asking and I think it provides an insight into the order of magnitude of Australian anti-climate-change lobbying spending:

> The five largest global oil companies – ExxonMobil, Shell, Chevron,
>   BP, and Total – have spent **a combined $US1 billion** ($1.44 billion) on
>   “misleading climate-related branding and lobbying” in the three years
>   since the Paris Agreement was signed, according to research from
>   InfluenceMap.

The same article provides a small graph to have a visual representation:

[image: Spending on climate branding]

While this certainly does not cover your question entirely, $US1 billion is a very rough figure to understand the size of the lobby in oil, coal and gas business related to climate change.